# torndb(MySQLdb) query params not work

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Like this:

```
In [43]: conn.query('select %s from topic order by %s limit 2', 'id', 'id desc')
Out[43]: [{'id': u'id'}, {'id': u'id'}]
In [44]: conn.query('select id from topic order by id desc limit 2')
Out[44]: [{'id': 10L}, {'id': 9L}]
```

Why the result is not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way query parameters are inserted into the query by the MySQLdb driver.

The first query is actually transformed into (watch the quotes):

```
select 'id' from topic order by 'id desc' limit 2
```

`'id'` here is a string, not the column name.

Comment: Thanks, and how to fix this and get the right result?

Comment: @Gee well, one option would be to use string formatting, but it is not recommended; in this case make sure you really trust the source for column name and order by clause: `conn.query('select %s from topic order by %s limit 2' % ('id', 'id desc'))`.

Comment: yeah, you are right, `%s` can only user by a variable